# time mismatch after convert with format_date

Tags: datetime

In my custom module, I converted time from database like ('17:00:00') with `format_date()`. After I converted this I got a wrong time (17:10). Please check my code, I am also naive drupal develper.

```
$form['departure_time'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#maxlength' => 10, 
  '#title' => t('Departure Time'),  
  '#default_value' => format_date(strtotime($data -> departure_time),'custom', 'H:m'),
  '#description' => t("You Need To Add Departure Time.<< 00:00"),
  '#required' => TRUE,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As listed in the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php lowercase m is for month. For minutes you should use i.

```
$dep= format_date(strtotime($data -> departure_time),'custom', 'H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just of note, you don't need to pass the date through `t()` as [`format_date()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7) handles this itself through `_format_date_callback()` [for reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/_format_date_callback/7).  You just have to pass in the langcode yourself.

Comment: This could have been a comment or a suggested edit to the answer

Comment: It's a completely different comment, not related to the accepted answer post - it's optional and more about coding standards than how to solve the posters issue.  If I were to add something related, it'd be more to do with that it's fairly clumsy to ask for a date via a textfield - a select box is a much better (and safer option).